# GGplot Stacked Barplot with individual colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart, stacked

I want to create a stacked barplot where the bottom category of each column is green and the upper category of each column goes from dark red to bright red (from left to right).

For example, using this code:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
                len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))

library(plyr)
# Sort by dose and supp
df_sorted <- arrange(df2, dose, supp) 

df_cumsum <- ddply(df_sorted, "dose",
                   transform, label_ypos=cumsum(len))


ggplot(data=df_cumsum, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(y=label_ypos, label=len), vjust=1.6, 
            color="white", size=3.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Is it possible?

Comment: If you want `ggplot` to use different colors, use different factors and pass the colors you want to `scale_fill_manual`

Comment: @Punintended can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to color the top bars differently, you need to create different factors for them. For instance by pasting the `supp` and `dose` column for the `OJ` values:

```
df_cumsum$supp <- as.character(df_cumsum$supp)
df_cumsum$supp <- ifelse(df_cumsum$supp == "OJ", paste(df_cumsum$supp, df_cumsum$dose, sep = ""), df_cumsum$supp)
df_cumsum$supp <- as.factor(df_cumsum$supp)

ggplot(data=df_cumsum, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(y=label_ypos, label=len), vjust=1.6, 
            color="white", size=3.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E74C3C", "#EC7063", "#F1948A", "#27AE60")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: hg]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want to do. Cheers